# EmberJS unit test compared to AngularJS

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, ember.js

I’m planning to build what will eventually be a large SPA with lots of data (in a grid).
It seems a good idea to use a MVC framework. I am mainly looking at AngularJS and EmberJS.
There are arguments for both, but it seems to me that EmberJS has some advantages that Angular does not. In particular, since I will have lots of data in a grid, I am afraid that choosing Angular will eventually cause me performance issues.

However, unit testing is also very important to me.

I haven’t been able to find much information about unit (not integration) testing of EmberJS.
Is Ember a significantly worse choice than Angular if unit testing is important? (As it currently stands)?

Please note that I am talking about unit tests, not integration tests. It seems to me that if I am going to build a large SPA, then it is important to test not just the surface of the app, but to be able to test each component/part/class individually and mock out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I've found unit testing in Ember to be relatively straightforward.

The are two things to make sure you understand in order to be successful writing Ember unit tests.

First, you will sometimes need to provide an object with a container (e.g. an Ember.DefaultContainer instance) when you create it for testing. The container is the crux of Ember's dependency injection mechanisms. Definitely need to learn about it.

Second, you will need to understand the Ember run loop in order to make sure the changes you make in your unit tests will propagate (e.g. computed properties with dependent keys becoming invalidated) before you assert that the new value is what you expect.

I would highly recommend reviewing the unit tests for Ember itself. You will find many useful techniques there.